How to get ImageBitmap from a Painter in Jetpack Compose?
I should use the Image() composable that takes image bitmap as its argument.
How can I convert a Painter to ImageBitmap in Compose?

Since Painter doesn't directly provide a way to convert to ImageBitmap, you need to draw the Painter onto a Bitmap. You can create an offscreen Canvas to draw the Painter and then convert the resulting Bitmap into an ImageBitmap.

Here is a solution from the asBitmap() function in Compose Multiplatform fork:
fun Painter.toImageBitmap(
    size: Size,
    density: Density,
    layoutDirection: LayoutDirection,
): ImageBitmap {
    val bitmap = ImageBitmap(size.width.toInt(), size.height.toInt())
    val canvas = Canvas(bitmap)
    CanvasDrawScope().draw(density, layoutDirection, canvas, size) {
        draw(size)
    }
    return bitmap
}

Usage:
val myPainter = ...
val size = myPainter.intrinsicSize // OR, for example, Size(300f, 100f)
val density = LocalDensity.current // OR, for example, Density(1f, 1f)
val direction = LocalLayoutDirection.current // OR, for example, LayoutDirection.Ltr
val myImageBitmap = myPainter.toImageBitmap(size, density, direction)

